# Which radioactive isotopes in food accumulate in a body, which ones are excreted?

Tags: food-safety, metabolism, potassium, half-life

A banana contains a natural radioactive isotope of potassium, however this one is not as dangerous since it gets excreted from the body and so the radiation does not accumulate in a body.

But what about other isotopes? I am particularly interested in isotopes with a long halflife, like iodine 129.

Comment: Iodine 131 has a half life of only 8 days.

Comment: You are referring to the pure stable isotope,  not any organic compounds that may contain any,  like FDG?

Comment: @CountIblis I corrected to iodine 129 which has a half-time of 15.7 million years.

Comment: @jiggunjer I also include organic compounds that contain such isotopes. The question could be reformulated: how safe is the food which is grown on the soil that contains different kinds of radioactive isotopes and animals that are fed on such products? I guess here the isotopes become part of the organic compounds.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you especially interested in those? An isotope with a halflife of 15 million years probably isn't even going to dacay in your body even if it's stays there until you die.

Comment: You can find some information here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sievert in case of long living radioisotopes, you can estimate the deposited energy in the body and apply the appropriate weighing factor to convert to the amount of milli-sieverts per year worth of biological exposure.